# Return to previous activity in android after inserting event of android calendar

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-calendar

I am adding event to **android calendar**. after inserting event, i want that control return back to activity from where it has been called so that i can get details of that event. I am using this code but it has some problems

```
            Uri uri = null;
            CalendarID = getNewEventId(getContentResolver(), uri);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra("beginTime", SelectedDate);
            intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
            intent.putExtra("rrule", "FsREQ=DAILY");
            intent.putExtra("endTime", SelectedDate + 60 * 60 * 1000);
            intent.putExtra("title", "Advance Scheduler Event");
            startActivity(intent);

            CalendarData Event_Data = EventDetails(CalendarID);
```

Comment: what kind of problem ?? if you want that your FirstActivity get Result from the SecondActivity , then use startActivityForResult() and override the method onActivityResult()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Use `startActivityForResult`
See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29

Answer (score 0):

The Calendar app has some bugs in its Intent handling. See my [blog post on Calendar's Intents](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/intents-of-androids-calendar-app/).

You should add your code to this issue as another comment: [Issue 28704](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28704). And do not forget to vote for the issue (click into the star in the blue header).